# how to get the data from a column of related to model?

Tags: laravel

there is a Product model with a name column, `Price` model with `product_id`, `size_id`, `min`, `max` columns. and a `Size` model with a `name` column.

the prices have foreignId of `size_id` column.

product relation is :

```
public function prices() { 
  return $this->hasmany(Price::class) 
}
```

Price model with `size_id`, `min`, `max` columns.

I can get min and max but how I can get the size from the size_id column.

```
@foreach($products->prices as $product)
<p>{{ $product->min}}</p>
<p>{{ $product->max}}</p>
**how to get the size
<p>{{ $product->size->name}}</p>**
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested relationship like below

```
$products=Product::with(['prices.size'])->find($id);
```

make sure you have relationship size in price model

```
public function size(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Size::class)
}
```